# What is the "List of Pre-Employment Inventions by Employee"?

Tags: job-offer, documentation

Today I've got a offer from the company at H.K.
then they give some document such as "List of Pre-Employment Inventions by Employee"

But I've never seen before that kinds of documents.
What is that the "List of Pre-Employment Inventions by Employee"?
and what happen if I write the list in this sheet?
and What am I supposed to do in this sheet?

Comment: sounds like a scam offer

Answer (score 11):

I don't think this is a standard thing, but the name is pretty clear. Have you invented anything? If you have, you are being asked to list all the things you've invented. I am quite confident that your new employer will have a policy "anything you invent while you work for us belongs to us" and that they enforce that by saying "you seem to have invented X, and it's not on the list of things you invented before you worked for us, therefore it belongs to us."

If you haven't invented anything, you can leave the list blank.

Comment: I have been asked to disclose prior inventions and intellectual-property claims as part of joining a company.  It was usually just a place in the employment agreement for me to write in any such.  It's insurance for the employee against the employer asserting claims on that work later (assuming the employer signs the document).